# regex vb.net ismatch always return true

Tags: regex, vb.net

am trying to implement validations using regex

The validation in aspx page works fine

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regexEmailValid" display="none" runat="server" ValidationExpression="(([a-z]|[A-Z]|[0-9]|[ ]|[-]|[_]|[@]|[.]|[!]|[$])*)*" ControlToValidate="txtUser" ErrorMessage="Invalid User Name Format"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

same one in code behind always returns true

```
Regex.IsMatch(UserName, "(([a-z]|[A-Z]|[0-9]|[ ]|[-]|[_]|[@]|[.]|[!]|[$])*)*")
```

tried adding **^** to start but still it always returns true

```
Regex.IsMatch(UserName, "^(([a-z]|[A-Z]|[0-9]|[ ]|[-]|[_]|[@]|[.]|[!]|[$])*)*")
```

What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: On what input string? `*` means zero too so this always match.

Comment: using test%= also returns true

Comment: It seems you need this `^[a-zA-Z0-9 _@.!$-]+$`

Comment: @revo thank you will try this am not so good at regex : ) i think i missed the $ for end of string..but your looks short and sweet :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are misusing alternations and capturing groups while you could have all those character classes into one. You also have `*` as quantifier which means zero or more. So regardless of anchors it matches. Your solution would be:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9 _@.!$-]+$
```

Comment: can these include character in any order in case i need to add remove in feature ?

Comment: Order doesn't matter. But some special characters like `-` and `^` should be escaped or treated carefully.

Comment: i noticed - at the end...what should i change if i should allow ^ in to my current regex ?

Comment: `^` has a special meaning when is used as first char in a character class. So avoid using it there if you mean a literal `^`. A safe way would be escaping. With escaping `\^` it doesn't matter where it resides.